# Estimating Safe Pulsed RF Power given Continuous Wave Power Rating

Tags: rf, microwave, radar

For a university project I am designing a RADAR transmit/receive module at 9.4 GHz. Right now I'm working on an input power limiter to protect an LNA, but my colleague designing the LNA quotes its maximum input power at +0 dBm. I've been so far unsuccessful in designing a PIN diode limiter to this specification, but I noticed that the power rating provided was for a CW signal.

My question is this: would the LNA be able to withstand a pulsed signal with a peak power greater than the CW rating? And if so, how can I estimate a safe limit for pulsed power knowing the pulse width and PRF of the input signal?

Answer (score 1):

There are two specs for  microwave maximum  input power.

1. Thermally safe limits : typ 20 dBm.
2. 1dB compression P1DB ~ 0dBm +/- design types.  Ultralinear +5dBm

[image]  [REF](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/SKY-0620PINLimiterDesignGuide-web.pdf)